# Review and Rating not working in admin and frontend in Magento2

Tags: magento2

> Grid Listing showing white page also New form and edit form showing white page in Admin.(Review and Rating)

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/A-1A/Magento2-Issues/issues/1

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17165

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

after

```
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Comment: Not working! Can You suggestion another solution?

Comment: I disabled all third party modules, give permission 777 and paste new review module in vendor/magento/module-review and also run composer update command

Comment: But  issue not solving